# Show loading message in jQuery Mobile when non-Ajax Form Submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, file-upload, form-submit

I am submitting a form in jQuery Mobile with `data-ajax="false"` on the form tag as well as `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so that I can utilize the file upload features in iOS 6. You have to disable the default Ajax form submission in order to actually pass the attached file.

I would like to show the default jQuery Mobile loading message using this:

```
$.mobile.loading('show');
```

as [defined in the docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html).

My form validates using this code:

```
$( document ).bind( "pageinit", function( event, data ) {   
    $("#contact-form").validate({
        // Custom validation messages
        messages: { contact_name: "Please enter your full name.", contact_phone: "Please enter a valid phone number.", contact_zip: "Please enter your shipping zip code."},
        errorElement: "p",
        submitHandler: function(form){

            //Get the data from the form fields and format correctly
            var name = $("#contact-form #contact_name").val();
            var email= $("#contact-form #contact_email").val();
            var phone= $("#contact-form #contact_phone").val();
            var zip= $("#contact-form #contact_zip").val();
            var message = $("#contact-form #contact_message").val();

            document.forms["contact-form"].submit();
         }
    });
});
```

How (in jQuery Mobile) can I show the default loading spinner when the user submits the form (by touching/clicking the submit button with `type="submit"`) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may wanna try something like this:

```
$( document ).bind( "pageinit", function( event, data ) {   

    $("#your_submit_button").click(function() {

        // When the button is clicked, show loading message
        $.mobile.loading('show');

        // Validate the form 
        $("#contact-form").validate({
            // Custom validation messages
            messages: { contact_name: "Please enter your full name.", contact_phone: "Please enter a valid phone number.", contact_zip: "Please enter your shipping zip code."},
            errorElement: "p",
            submitHandler: function(form){

            //Get the data from the form fields and format correctly
            var name = $("#contact-form #contact_name").val();
            var email= $("#contact-form #contact_email").val();
            var phone= $("#contact-form #contact_phone").val();
            var zip= $("#contact-form #contact_zip").val();
            var message = $("#contact-form #contact_message").val();

            document.forms["contact-form"].submit();

            // Hide the loading message
            $.mobile.loading('hide');

         }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps